# How do I know if I can use this external crate in my rust contract?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm writing a smart contract and want to know which external crates will work and which won't. I don't want to go through the trouble of importing them into my contracts and checking if everything compiles properly every time I want to use a crate.

As an example, say I wanted to use the [rand](https://crates.io/crates/rand) crate but then found out it wasn't compatible. How could I check this beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, anything that supports `wasm32-unknown-unknown` will be compatible with your smart contract. An easy way to check this is by going to `crates.io` and checking there. In your example, when going to the [rand](https://crates.io/crates/rand) page and doing a quick find all for `wasm32`, you can see at the bottom that `wasm32-unknown-unknown` is not "automatically supported":
[image: wasm support for rand crate]

This is a good rule to follow, but there are edge cases where a crate might compile to wasm32 but fail at runtime for incompatible functionality.